# How to make RAID-1 (almost) full bandwidth when processing the sequential write/read?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, raid, bandwidth

When I read OSTEP [chapter 38 about RAID](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/file-raid.pdf), it says in p10:

> The 1/2 penalty assumes a naive read/write pattern for mirroring; a more sophisticated
> approach that issued large I/O requests to **differing parts** of each mirror could **potentially
> achieve full bandwidth**

---

###### sequential read

with sequential read, from p9

> Let’s say we issue the read of
> 0 to disk **0**, the read of 1 to disk 2, the read of 2 to disk **1**, and the read of
> 3 to disk 3

it has used **differing parts** of each mirror, but due to the skipped read of 2, one **unused** read of 2 to disk 0 causes `(N/2) · S` speed where `N` is disk number and `S` is full bandwidth of a **single** disk.

---

###### sequential write

As the book says, due to the copy, the speed is half of the full bandwidth.

> the RAID internally would write it to **both** disk
> 0 and disk 1. Thus, we can conclude that the maximum bandwidth obtained during sequential writing to a mirrored array is ( N/
> 2
> · S), or **half** the
> peak bandwidth.

Q:

How to achieve the almost full bandwidth of RAID-1 with some methods when processing some specific request sequences?

Comment: Impossible to answer as it depends heavily on the type of multiplexer and disks.